# Batch File Techinque for Set /A and quoting

Tags: batch-file, coding-style, set, quotes

I've always wondered about how and when to use quotes if my script is making a calculation. For example,

`Set /A exp=%some%+(!calculation!-0)`.

I know, if the line uses parentheses, and I'm inside an `IF` block, I should use

`Set /A exp="%some%+(!calculation!-0)"`.

The quotes just go around the part after the equals.

Aside from that, quoting from the variable name to the end of the line,

`Set /A "exp=%some%+(!calculation!-0)"`

seems to work as well.

I'm wondering, is there a "proper" way to use `SET /A`? What's the *correct/best* technique for batch scripts? When should I use quotes? Are they mostly optional unless one gets an error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes more sense, if you try it without `/a`: if you use `"`after the `=`, it will become part of the variable; if you use it before `=`, it delimits the expression (usualy used to avoid unintended or insert intended trailing spaces in a variable)

```
C:\>set x="1+3"
C:\>set x
x="1+3"

C:\>set "x=2+5"
C:\>set x
x=2+5

C:\>set x=text  
C:\>echo -%x%-
-text  -

C:\>set "x=text"  
C:\>echo -%x%-
-text-
```

(note, there are two "unintended" spaces after `set x=text` and `set "x=text"`)

with `/a`, the qoutes are just stripped (`/a` was added to the former `set`command from "good old DOS")

Comment: But the question is about the use of quotes specially when `SET` is used to calculate expressions with `/a`

Comment: Swwwweeeet - thank you Stephan ~ totally makes sense now. Thank you, I've always wondered about that.